Junit 5 TestExecutionListener executionFinished allways returns success
I registered a listener in Junit 5.
public void executionFinished(TestIdentifier testIdentifier, TestExecutionResult testExecutionResult) {

and no matter what happens testExecutionResult is always successful. I forced a null pointer in test and it still reports success.
I have also a custom extension for the test and handleTestExecutionException captures the exception, so the problem relies on the listener.
I am runing junit-jupiter-engine 5.10.3 and junit-platform-launcher 1.11.3 (tried also 1.10.5).
Here is how I registered the hook:
    public CustomTestExecutionListener runTest(Class testClass) {
        LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                .selectors(selectClass(testClass)).build();
        Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
        CustomTestExecutionListener listener = new CustomTestExecutionListener();

        launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
        launcher.execute(request);
        return listener;
    }

public class CustomTestExecutionListener extends SummaryGeneratingListener {

    @Override
    public void executionFinished(TestIdentifier testIdentifier, TestExecutionResult testExecutionResult) {
        super.executionFinished(testIdentifier, testExecutionResult);
...

